# Create password protected influxDB

Tags: c#, grafana, influxdb

I am working on a C# application with InfluxDB and Grafana. I am using InfluxData.Net (https://github.com/pootzko/InfluxData.Net#createdatabaseasync). I have to create a password protected Influx database. My code is:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = OnHandleSSl;
var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);

InfluxDbClient _influxDbClient = new InfluxDbClient(Server, Username, Password, InfluxDbVersion.v_1_3, QueryLocation.FormData, client);
var response = await _influxDbClient.Database.CreateDatabaseAsync(_dbSettings.DatabaseName);
```

Issue is that when i go to Grafana on the server and add new data source with this database, data source works fine and does not show any error regarding username/password. Even the data in the database is shown in the grafana. I am using InfluxDB image. I have also tried to enable **INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED** in DockerFile of InfluxDB. My DockerFile is:

```
FROM influxdb:1.7.6

ENV TZ=America/Los_Angeles
ENV INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED true

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

When i run the image created from this DockerFile, i don't get **INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED** entry in **influxdb.conf** file.

How can i make a password protected influx database through influxDB image ?  What can be the possible issue ? I am stuck and unable to create the password protected database. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share you influxdb configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication must defined in the InfluxDB server configuration. You can't define it on the DB level.

See doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/authentication_and_authorization/#set-up-authentication

Comment: Thanks @Jan Garaj. I have updated the question, can you kindly have a look at it again. Is there any way i can make a database password protected without creating any user, as it is mentioned the link, that you have shared, that we have to create an admin user. Actually, my requirement is that i dont want to create any user. I have to create two influxDBs, one would be normal and one would be password protected.